# How to get number of users in User class and schedule a daily task

Tags: parse-platform

I am unable to get the total number of users in my USER class through JavaScript. And I want to schedule a task that calculates the number of users in my USER class every midnight.

Answer (score 0):

To get total number of users -

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); // FOR QUERYING USERS
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
     // results.length - total number of objects available.
  },
  error: function(error) {
  }
});
```

To Schedule a TASK at **every regular interval**, you have to use **[Jobs](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs)** in Cloud Code. 
Steps -

1. Write a method in Javascript as per documentation.
2. Host it using deploy to Cloud code.
3. Go to - **Jobs** available on LHS of your Dashboard of your app. Usually @ https://parse.com/apps/APP_NAME/cloud_code/jobs
4. Then make a schedule. There is an option of executing task at particular time, everyday. Of course, you can use it to make your choice of Interval using code.